# time complexity (with respect of n input)

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

I was asked if what time complexity if this:

What is the time complexity (with respect of n) of this algorithm:

```
k=0
for(i = n / 2 ; i < n ; i++ ) {
   for( j=0 ; j < i ; j++)
      k = k + n / 2
}
```

choices was : `a. O(n)` `b. O(n/2)` `c. O(n log(n)` and `d. O(n^2)`

`can have a multiple answers.`

i know the algorithm above is `d. O(n^2)` but i came with with `a. O(n)` since it is looking for `complexity of n` only?.

if you are to have this question. how would you answer it.?? im so curious about the answer.

Comment: "With respect to n" just means that the *n* is the input variable to this algorithm, and so your first idea was the right one (d).

Comment: trincot is right - the complexity of this algorithm is O(n^2). I would like to explain in details the logic of this concept. The outer loop runs for n/2 iterations. For each iteration i (i starts from n/2), the inner loop runs i iterations. The calculation inside the inner loop can be computed in O(1) time complexity. which is negligible. Therefore the total number of iterations (outer & inner loop) is: n/2 + n/2 + 1 + n/2 + 2 + ... + n Note that this is a sum of arithmetic series, and it equals 3n(n+2)/4 Therefore you get O(n^2) time complexity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is O(n²).

This is easy to understand. I will try to make you understand it.

See, the outer `for` loop block is executed `n - n/2 = n/2` times.

Of course it depends whether the number `n` is even or odd. If it's even then the outer loop is executed `n/2` times. If it's odd then it's executed for `(n-1)/2` times.

But for time complexity, we don't consider this. We just assume that the outer `for` loop is executed `n/2` times where `i` starts from `n/2` and ends at `n - 1` (because the terminating condition is `i < n` and not `i <= n`).

For each iteration of the outer loop, the inner loop executes `i` times.

For example, for every iteration, inner loop starts with `j = 0` to `j = i - 1`. This means that it executes `i` times (not `i - 1` times because `j` starts from 0 and not from 1).

Therefore, for 1st iteration the inner loop is executed `i = n / 2` times. `i = n / 2 + 1` for 2nd iteration and so on upto `i = n - 1` times.

Now, the total no. of times the inner loop executes is `n/2 + (n/2 + 1) + (n/2 + 2) + ... + (n - 2) + (n - 1)`. It's simple math that this sums up to `(3n² - n)/2` times.

So, the time complexity becomes O((3n² - n)/2).

But we ignore the `n` term because `n² > n` and the constant terms  because for every `n` they will remain the same.

Therefore, the final time complexity is O(n²).

Hope this helps you understand.